# RAD 9.6 - Error while starting WAS V9.0 Application Client

Tags: ibm-rad

I am trying to run a WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0 Application Client using Run configurations from RAD 9.6 and I am getting the below error.

*Error: Could not find or load main class Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\javaext;C:\Program*

While researching I found a similar error in WAS ADMIN JYTHON SCRIPTS due to the spaces in the folder name where WebSphere is installed. Could this be because of the same reason?

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI79624

Please advise if there is an issue with RAD 9.6 to run application client if the WebSphere Application Server installation directory name has spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by installing the WAS in a folder without spaces.